# Filtering records from a certain date month

Tags: mysql, sql

[table flights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS0Ts.png)

I have this table that shows records of passengers flights, im trying to retrieve the passenger details from the table "passengers" but only for passengers who has more than 5 flights in a given date duration.

Tried this query for passengers who had more than 5 times in the month of October but its not working....

```
  SELECT * FROM passengers 
WHERE pass_id IN (SELECT pass_id from flights
where f_date BETWEEN '2020-10-1' and '2020-10-31')
HAVING count(pass_id)>5;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right idea but you are missing `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM passengers p
WHERE p.pass_id IN (SELECT f.pass_id 
                    FROM flights f
                    WHERE f_date BETWEEN '2020-10-01' and '2020-10-31'
                    GROUP BY pass_id
                    HAVING count(*) > 5
                   );
```

Comment: Interesting, im still learning but still i was somewhat close, thank you!